# reducing space between sections

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I want to reduce space between  between specified sections sections (C and D) only in my document. I don' want disturb my rest document.
Here is a minimum code

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{book}              % Book class in 11 points
\parindent0pt  \parskip10pt             % make block paragraphs
\raggedright                            % do not right justify

\title{\bf An Example of Book Class}    % Supply information

\begin{document}                       
\frontmatter                           
\maketitle                            
\tableofcontents                        
\mainmatter                             
\part{A Part Heading}                  
\chapter{A Main Heading}               
\section{A Subheading A}                  
The following sectioning commands are available:
\section{A Subheading B}  
The following sectioning commands are available:
 \section{A Subheading C}                
 THE SPACE AFTER THIS LINE SHOULD BE REDUCED THEN DEFAULT VALUE.
 \section{A Subheading D}  
  THE SPACE BETWEEN SECTION C AND D SHOULD BE REDUCED
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are aware that this depends on the `documentclass` most likely?

Comment: what does mean space between sections? vertical space before heading?

Comment: try `\newcommand\addvspace{\vspace{-1em}}` in preambul and `\addvspace\section{A Subheading D}`

Comment: @touhami: Isn't `\addvspace` not already a core command?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I mean `\mtaddvspace`, sorry.

Comment: It worked with \Caddvspace. Thanx you all.

Comment: @touhami, a simple `\vspace{-1em}\section{Bla and bla}` should do, as it is an one-off. Not that futzing around with spacing is a good idea in general, better try to figure out *why* it looks dodgy in the first place.

Comment: @vonbrand sorry I didn't understand your comment. `\mtaddvspace\section` is more latex spirit. (sorry again)

Comment: @touhami: I am confused. `\mtaddvspace`?  Is that a core command or in `book.cls`? It looks like a macro from `minitoc` rather

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it's newcommand (mt) from my name ;-)

Comment: @touhami: ;-) It's not a generally available command then ;-)